# Edit to correct broken link was rejected

Tags: support, broken-link

An answer to a post had a link to a no-longer-existing page. I found the referenced page at archive.org and edited the answer by simply adding the archive.org prefix -- so anyone clicking the link would see the page instead of seeing a 404. I did not make any other change to call attention to it.

This edit was rejected, saying that I should post a different answer or add a comment (I did the latter). I'd like to argue with that, but don't know of a way to engage with the person who rejected the post. Does any way exist of doing that?

I do not understand how adding an archive.org prefix, when all that does is make the broken link work, is an inappropriate edit. Is there a policy around this that I had not known?

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Do you have a link to the suggested edit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/168482  @ProgramFOX

Comment: If you are indeed referring to the edit that @Mat linked, the original link is currently working. Maybe that's the reason for the rejection.

Comment: Same for those: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/300415 the links work (with a redirect); replacing that with an archive.org link isn't a good idea;

Comment: Are we really referring to suggested edits that were rejected back in 2011 and 2012, or is there a newer one that you were talking about?

Comment: @animuson: Looking at the user's [edit suggestion history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/215175/j-merrill?tab=activity&sort=suggestions): Yes we are. Wat.