# Why was my edit to fix a dead link rejected?

Tags: discussion

I have understood that it is generally a good practice to correct a dead link in a post whenever you run into one. For example:

- [Should I approve edits that simply appear to update a hyperlink?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303536/6413377)
- [Updating dead links in answers: edit or comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300033/6413377)

Can you tell the main reason / what I can do better when updating a dead link to a working one like in [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18241239)?

Was it the wrong material which I linked to or were the reviewers thinking it was a superfluous change? Or should the link actually be removed totally from the post?

There is almost a [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280234/6413377) question, but in that case the link "fixed" was not finally broken but in my case the original link is still offering ***Page Not Found***.

Comment: Nobody but the actual reviewers can tell you why they chose to reject your edit. Personally, the fact that you left the old link in the post, but commented it, would have confused me a bit. If you are fixing the link, no reason to leave the old one around.

Comment: @yivi Yes I should have removed the old link. It IS in the review history and thus no need to leave it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you commented out the old link, and you posted a link to a different domain, all with the description "changed link to working one". Especially when changing the domain of the link, you'll have to explain why you're changing that.

Using the domain and slug, I found the link https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/effective-javatm-programming/0201310058/ch02.html which does appear to be still online, albeit behind a paywall.

I just went ahead and [edited the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13046909/revisions), because I do think the link you found is more appropriate, given it's posted by the author of the book.

Comment: Ok. Can you yet tell the reason why the domain should not be changed? I mean it was pointing to chapter in a well known book(?). Is there some _preferred domains_?

Comment: Look at it from a reviewer's perspective. You changed the domain without explaining why. You could as well have changed the link to an ad-ridden domain you own.

Comment: Ok so the final answer might be that my comment should have been like: _changed to different domain because old link was dead and new links in the same domain  are trial/ behindpaywall_? But I still not get what is wrong with changing the domain when link is dead.

Comment: That would definitely have helped.

Comment: @pirho you have to let that go. The problem was a lack of explanation which made the change look suspicious, not that the act itself was wrong. As long as it looks suspicious, don't expect people to follow the link to see if it is correct or not.

Comment: @Gimby Already have no problem :) But interested still if there is information why changing domain of link makes it suspicious. Well, maybe I ask a new question about that then.

Comment: @pirho I explained that in my first comment.

Comment: @pirho, no need to ask a new question. Just use common sense. A change to a completely different link could look suspicious for a random reviewer. It **should** look suspicious if _you_ are the one reviewing. Better comments would help reviewers to understand what's going on, that's it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes but how does it then help to provide a explanation? Shouldn't the reviewer anyway check the old link bad & the new link if it is such like ad-ridden? I mean i hope they do not trust to edit comments only in therse cases. But good comment for me in that sense that when fixing you should check also that the new site is somehow _clean_.

Comment: @yivi Ok I was thinking that if I some day do the reviews I'll check the links whatever the comments say. But good to know for possible future reviewing as a check-list-item.